# What causes QGIS 2 Plugin Manager Error from showPluginManagerWhenReady?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, spanish

there.
when i open the plugin manager in qgis, i get this:

Ocurrió un error durante la ejecución del siguiente código:
pyplugin_installer.instance().showPluginManagerWhenReady()

> A Google translation of the Spanish is: An error occurred during the execution of
>   the following code

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

NameError: name 'pyplugin_installer' is not defined

any help?

Answer (score 2):

Alguno de los plugins instalados desde el repositorio oficial te está dando problemas. En mi caso fue el 'MetaSearch'.

Para averiguarlo fui a la carpeta /home/felix/.qgis2/python/plugins, moví todo los plugins a otra temporal y luego fui uno a uno colocándolos y probando el qgis

> ### Google Translation:
>
> Some of the plugins installed from the official repository is giving you problems. In my case it was the 'MetaSearch'.
>
> To find out I went to the folder / home/felix/.qgis2/python/plugins, moved all the plugins to another time and then went one to one placing and testing the qgis